# Is "for eating" a joke?

Tags: meaning

> Matthew and Maggie came with their two children and a  sackful of
>   chickens. Maggie emptied the sack into the yard and  three red banty
>   chickens clucked and scattered.
>
> "They are for you," she told Sarah. "For eating."
>
> Sarah loved the chickens. She clucked back to them and fed  them
>   grain. They followed her, shuffling and scratching primly in  the
>   dirt. I knew they would not be for eating.

This is from the novel "Sarah, Plain and Tall". Did Maggie think the chickens were for eating but Sarah didn't? Or is it about their eggs? Or Is it a Joke?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maggie was making it clear that the chickens were for meat, not for eggs.  But Sarah loved them as pets,  and the author is telling us that he/she knew that this would happen.  It's not a joke, it's more of a fond comment about Sarah's kind nature.